# RequestRecipientToken Cause of sporadic error code 123?

Tags: docusignapi

This issue is uncommon and I can't see how this request is different from any others of ours. I send a request something like this through the PHP API:

```
<ns1:RequestRecipientToken>
  <ns1:EnvelopeID>...</ns1:EnvelopeID>
  <ns1:ClientUserID>1</ns1:ClientUserID>
  <ns1:Username>Jeff...</ns1:Username>
  <ns1:Email>jeff@...</ns1:Email>
  <ns1:AuthenticationAssertion>
    <ns1:AssertionID>(guid)</ns1:AssertionID>
    <ns1:AuthenticationInstant>2013-08-16T00:00:00.00</ns1:AuthenticationInstant>
    <ns1:AuthenticationMethod>Password</ns1:AuthenticationMethod>
    <ns1:SecurityDomain>MyDomain</ns1:SecurityDomain>
  </ns1:AuthenticationAssertion>
  <ns1:ClientURLs>...</ns1:ClientURLs>
</ns1:RequestRecipientToken>
```

And get back this

```
<soap:Body>
<soap:Fault>
  <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
  <faultstring>The recipient you have identified is not a valid recipient of the specified envelope. </faultstring>
  <faultactor>https://www.docusign.net/api/3.0/api.asmx</faultactor>
  <detail>
    <ErrorCode xmlns="missing in Web.Config">123</ErrorCode>
    <ErrorReason xmlns="missing in Web.Config">The recipient you have identified is not a valid recipient of the specified envelope.</ErrorReason>
  </detail>
</soap:Fault>
```

Like I said, our document creation and signing usually works, so I am looking for word if there is any uncommon user workflow that causes this that we don't know about, or if there is a bug, if anyone else has run into this lately. Thanks.

Causes I have ruled out:
1) I logged into the docusign website to find the envelope and make sure everything was there and matched
2) The recipient name, email, and ClientUserId match, because I used the strategy of retrieviing the recipient info immediately before doing the RequestRecipientToken call.

By the way I don't think Docusign should be using Stack Overflow as the support forum, but they are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the problem is that the recipients name does not match the request, and only happens for names with certain special characters.

You identify the recipient in the request by two fields: username and email. The email matches, however you can easily inadvertently lose some special characters if you store the name in the database. A simple example would be the last name O'Brien, but it can also occur because of non-ascii characters in the name.

The solution is to no longer send the RequestRecipientToken request using the name retrieved from the database. Instead, start by requesting the envelope over the API by envelope ID, which returns the list of recipients, including their names and emails. Pick the right recipient by matching on a different field besides name such as email. Use the name of this recipient, as defined in the envelope details, as the name to specify in the RequestRecipientToken request.

Answer (score 1):

Possibilities that first come to mind are:

- The envelope has been voided.
- The envelope has expired.
- The recipient is indeed not a recipient of that envelope.

Have any of these envelopes where you've experienced this sporadic error ever been voided or expired?  And what happens when you get this error, do you simply make the same exact call again right after and this time it works?  I'd start by confirming basics like that.  That error code of 123 is also suspicious to me - haven't seen that before and I'm wondering if that's coming from the DocuSign platform.

For the 3rd potential cause listed above, are you positive that you are always referencing the correct email, username, and clientUserId combination to correctly identify the recipient?  If anyone of those is not exactly the same as when that recipient was added to the envelope then you will get that error.

Comment: In a specific case in front of me, I logged into the Docusign website to verify that the envelope is there and ready. Your 3rd potential cause is the most likely, but in this case, I even tried retrieving the recipient information from Docusign first, and then using the returned information, which was the same as what I send anyway.